# How to fix errors in singly linked list method append

Tags: python, append, singly-linked-list

I have two class a node and a linked. My error is coming from the append method located in the `linkedList class`.

I try to `.append(10)` but it does not print the 10 out only the 5 when it should be appending to the end. By chance can anyone see the error?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
class linkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def append(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = newNode
            return
        else:
            lastNode = self.head
            while lastNode.next != None:
                lastNode = lastNode.next
            lastNode.next = newNode
    def prepend(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = newNode
            return
        else:
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head = newNode
    def insertAfterNode(self, prevNode, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        newNode.next = prevNode.next
        prevNode.next = newNode
    def printList(self):
        curNode = self.head
        while curNode.next != None:
            print(curNode.data)
            curNode = curNode.next
    def deleteNode(self, key):
        curNode = self.head
        if curNode != None and curNode.data == key:
            self.head = curNode.next
            curNode = None
            return
        else:
            prev = None
            while curNode != None and curNode.data != key:
                prev = curNode
                curNode = curNode.next
            if curNode == None:
                print("The data is not found in the list")
                return
            else:
                prev.next = curNode.next
                curNode = None

# Testing the Linked List
linkedLst = linkedList()
linkedLst.append(5)
linkedLst.append(10)
linkedLst.printList()
linkedLst.prepend(15)
linkedLst.printList()
linkedLst.insertAfterNode(linkedLst.head.next, 6)
linkedLst.insertAfterNode(linkedLst.head.next.next, 8)
linkedLst.printList()
linkedLst.deleteNode(6)
linkedLst.deleteNode(20)
linkedLst.printList()
```

Expected result should be `5 10, 15 5 10, 15 6 8 5 10, 15 8 5 10`, and then an error message saying it can not be deleted. 
However, I am getting `5, 15 5, 15 6 8 5, 15 8 5` and it excludes the `10.`
I am running on vim and have python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at method `printList`, the while loop stops when `curNode.next` is `None` which is when `curNode` is the last node. The last node didn't get a change to be printed. The element 10 is there, it's just not getting printed.

Also, just a minor thing, it's good practice to use CapWords for class names so your code is consistent with the [recommended style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).